# How to correctly redirect user after authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-redux` and currently I have a bool `isAuthenticated` property in my global state and if this is true it will redirect to `/home` component.

Is there a better approach to the one I implemented? How can I resolve the output error?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "./actions";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const myState = useSelector(
    state => state.authentication
  );

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    dispatch(login(values.email, values.password));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myState.isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/home")
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

}
```

Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

`[isAuthenticated, history]` is this acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better approach to the one I implemented? How can I resolve the output error?

The answer depends on where you keep your logic. If you keep all your logic in components' states, the `useEffect` way is perfectly fine.

To resolve the warning, just put the history to the useEffect inputs as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (myState.isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/home")
    }
  }, [myState.isAuthenticated, history]);
```

Now the useEffect will be triggered every time the reference to the history object changes. If you're using React Router, then the `history` instance is most probably mutable and it will not change, and hence not trigger the useEffect. So it should be safe to include it in the UseEffect dependency array.

Comment: That's what I did to solve this issue but I thought there would be a better approach since I'm still new to useEffect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The better way is always create separate **PrivateRoute** component which handle your authentication. If you go through react router official documentation they have given a good example of authentication:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const myState = useSelector(
    state => state.authentication
  );
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        myState.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

You can use wrap it in layer like this:

```
<Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
```

In that way you dont have to manually track your authentication.
Here is complete demo from react-router website:https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow